# How to convert CollectionAccumulator[(Double, Double)] to a SparkdataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator[(Double, Double)]`
And I have added the rows to it while streaming.

Now I want to convert it to a DataFrame for further processing. But I am not sure how to achieve it.

### Edit

Adding the code snippet of how I populate the accumulator:

```
val strmquery = dataFramedummy.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row]() {

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = true

  override def process(row: Row): Unit = {
    println(s">> Processing ${row}")
    accumulator.add((row.getAs("Field1").asInstanceOf[Double], row.getAs("Filed2").asInstanceOf[Double]))
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    // do nothing
  }
}).outputMode("append").start()
```

Comment: Can you add the code on how you add data to it?

Comment: @Shaido: Added the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert you accumulator to list and than create dataset out of that.

```
val accumulator :org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator[(Double, Double)] = ???
spark.createDataset(accumulator.value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to convert it now.